# Программа вопрос - ответ

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите, пожалуйста.
Выводится вопрос, рандомные. Например: Прозвище Лаки Лучано. Ответ должен быть: Счастливчик.
Но тут что-то не так, я пробовал с if, и все такое. Но не понимаю, как можно реализовать это. И надо ли словарь тут?
Спасибо.[image: Программа вопрос - ответ]

Comment: Убрать кортежи внутри словаря, и оставить только словарь?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Какое-то у вас странное понимание словарей. У вас получилось множество из кортежей, хотя так тоже можно - ваш выбор...
Но если вы хотите именно словарь, то:

Словарь - тип данных, состоящий из пар значений в стиле (ключ: значение). Например:

```py
kek = {"Машина": "Mercedes", "Число колёс": 4, "Какой-то список": [5, 7.32, "Вася"]}
```

Примерный пример программы, как я вижу её в базовом представлении:

```py
import random

kek = {
    "Машина": "Mercedes", 
    "Число колёс": 4, 
    "Какой-то список": [5, 7.32, "Вася"],
    }

while True:
    question = random.choice(list(kek.keys()))
    user_answer = input(f"{question}?\n")

    if user_answer == kek[question]:
        print("Верно!")
    else:
        print("Вы ошиблись :(")
```

P.s.: если что-то хотите изменить - меняйте. Если будут вопросы - задавайте.

Comment: Тогда как можно реализовать такую программу вопрос - ответ? Не подскажете?

Comment: @BrendonHarrison я изменил, проверьте

Comment: Спасибо, благодарю.